# Knowing the exact method call when tap on iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there any quick way to know which method is called when we do any activity on iOS app. I have the code but this is written by some other team and I am trying to find out the action that is happening when I tap on iPad. Is there any way to know about it. I tried putting break points but it does not help.

Comment: first you can ask them :). second check the story board connections. if storyboard is not used then try looking at the methods names. Never tried it but I believe you can also monitor the stack trace while the app is running

Comment: skim the code for methods in view controllers that start with `- (IBAction)`, these are the methods called by the interface interaction  in most cases if the views were configured via IB.

Comment: While the OP is stating that they are trying to track the "action", that doesn't necessarily mean that it's done in Interface Builder. Maybe it's still programmatic. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following ways out of many can help you:

- Find out all methods that have *IBAction* mention in the start in your `.m` file. Put a break point on them.
- Goto `.storyboard` or `.XIB` file of your respective controller, in the right pane check `Connection inspector`. This inspector will be divided into two halves first belongs to IBOutlet, you have to check the second one which is IBAction. Find them in your `.m` file and put a break point on it.
- Check `.h` file for any IBAction methods, find its implementation in `.m` and put  a break point on it.
- Trace any IBAction selector(s) specified via `addTarget` function.

Hope it can help!!